# Calculate the tangent plane of $x^2y+xy^2$ at $(a,b)=(1, -1)$

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

Write the equation of the tangent plane at the point $(a, b, f(a, b))$ on the graph of $f$.

The equation to the tangent plane for partial derivatives is given as:

$$z = f(a.b)+(x-a)\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a,b) + (y-b)\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(a,b)$$

For the following calculation:  $x^2y+xy^2$ at $(a.b)=(1, -1)$

My workings:
$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 2xy+y^2=2y$ at $x=1$

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=2x+2xy=-2x$ at $y=-1$

$f(a.b) = -1$

Plugging this all in: $-1+2y(x-1)-2x(y+1)=-1-2y-2x$

However the answer should be $x+y+z=0$. Where did my approach go wrong?

Comment: The partial derivatives are being evaluated at $(a,b)$ not at a or b, evaluating the partial derivatives how you have done it doesn't make sense since these are functions of two variables. The partial derivative with respect to y is incorrect. $f(a,b)$ is not -1.

Comment: Your formula say $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a,b)$, not  $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f(x, y) = x^2y + xy^2$

Given point is $P (1, -1, 0)$ as $f(1, -1) = 0$. *You calculated $f(1, -1)$ incorrectly.*

Also, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 2 xy + y^2 = - 1$ (at point $P$). *You made a mistake as you plugged in only $x =1$ at point $P$ instead of $x = 1, y = -1$.*

Similarly, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = x^2 + 2 xy = - 1$ (at point $P$)

So equation of plane is,

$z = - (x- 1) - (y + 1) \implies x + y + z = 0$

Answer (score 1):

$z = x^2y + xy^2\\
0 = z- x^2y - xy^2\\
\nabla (z- x^2y + xy^2) = (-2xy-y^2, -x^2 - 2xy,  1)$

This gives us the normal vector to the tangent plane at any point on the surface.

Evaluate at $(1,-1,0)$ and we get $(1,1,1)$ as the normal vector.

$ x + y + z = d$

And, find the appropriate $d$ for our point $(1,-1,0).$

$ x + y + z = 0$